# Angular 4 Wait Condition Using Java Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, angular, maven, selenium

I am having issues writing a wait condition for java selenium that works for both Angular 4 and Angular 1. I currently have a solution that works for Angular 1 which is as follows:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularHasFinishedProcessing() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return Boolean.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                    "return (window.angular !== undefined) &&" +
                            " (angular.element(document).injector() !== undefined) &&" +
                            " (angular.element(document).injector().get('$http').pendingRequests.length === 0)").toString());
        }
    };
}

public static void waitOnAngular(WebDriver driver){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    wait.until(AdditionalConditions.angularHasFinishedProcessing());
}
```

I am looking for some JavaScript to extend this apply() method to work with angular 4 or a different solution that people have had success with in getting selenium to wait until the angular $http requests have loaded along with all the views.

See the pom.xml file below to see what versions of selenium-java I am version.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ridebooker</groupId>
<artifactId>auto-tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Ridebooker Auto Tests</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codepine.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>testrail-api-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.11-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.18</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>

                        <!--To use different properties when ran from inside your IDE change your run config to pass
                         the VM a parameter such as:
                         -Denv.HOME=local
                         -Denv.HOME=staging
                         -Denv.HOME=production
                        -->

                        <environment>${env.HOME}</environment>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found some time before in SO and use it quite successful to wait for angular. But i don't know if it works for both.

```
final String script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];\n" +
        "var rootSelector = \'body\';\n" +
        "var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);\n" +
        "\n" +
        "try {\n" +
        "    if (angular) {\n" +
        "        window.angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "    else {\n" +
        "        callback();\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "} catch (err) {\n" +
        "    callback(err.message);\n" +
        "}";

((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeAsyncScript(script, new Object[0]);
```

Comment: I had no joy with the script you provided, do you or anyone else have something similar for Angular 4?

Comment: unfortunately not, thats all i found and use

Comment: It doesn't work with angular 4+, as 'angular' variable is not accessible from javascript anymore

Answer (score 0):

> window.getAllAngularTestabilities()

is the function you want. Here is an example:

```
var testabilities = window.getAllAngularTestabilities();
var count = testabilities.length;
var decrement = function() {
    count--;
    if (count === 0) {
        return;
    }
};
var waitForAllAngular2 = function() {
    try {
        testabilities.forEach(function(testability) {
            testability.whenStable(decrement);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
};
waitForAllAngular2();
```

This makes sure that Angular is stable before doing any actions.